# Facing issues with isClickable() when using in appium and wdio for ios Automation

Tags: jasmine, appium, webdriver-io

I am completely new to app automation.
My tech stack for iOS automation: typescript - jasmine - wdio - appium to write my automation script in.

When I use statement like,  $(selector).isClickable() in my code, it calls to execute an async script. Due to which other operations in the script are failing. What can I use instead of this?

The app I am trying to automate is a Native iOS App .

Answer (score 0):

Webdriverio v7 supports only async mode , here everything returns a promise . so you have to use await to wait for the promise to be resolved

```
describe("Some function", function(){ //describe cannot be async

   it("Some function", async function(){ //it should be async
      let element = await $('selector')
      element.isClickable()
      //you can do this in one line as
      await (await $('selector')).isClickable()
   })
})
```

Comment: i am currently using wdio/sync in my package.json file for handling my promises or instead of async await.  current version:   "@wdio/sync": "^6.11.0",